# Is it ok to have a non persistent variable in an entity?

Tags: orm, persistence, entity, object-persistence, object-relational-model

When using an ORM, is it breaking some kind of good practice to have a model class with a few non-persistent properties, which are only used for calculations, and then can be safely dropped?

Let's say we have a Product. This Product has list of possible Options. An Option may have a price impact on the Product. We also have a set of Rules, which say that when one Option is selected, then the price of another Option changes.

When we add a Product to an Order, along with a selection of Options, we first need to recalculate the price of all the Options based on the rules affecting each selected Option. Then we can calculate the final price of the Product with all its selected Options.

In this example, the Option could have a calculatedPrice property, which would only have meaning within the context of the selected Options, and could be safely dropped after the Product has been added to the Order.

Is there a more correct way to think about this problem, or is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to have `@Transient` properties.

Some people may consider it wrong and insist on having a separate class that is almost the same as the entity, but having the additional fields, but that is unnecessary code duplication. Your approach is what I'd do.

Comment: I'm glad there is even a name for that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The other approach, which is used in a large and ghastly e-commerce system i work with, is to have a parallel structure of transient objects containing the computed information. So, in parallel to the Order, there is an OrderPrice. For each Item in the order, there is an ItemPrice. If an Item has a set of Options, then the ItemPrice will have a set of OptionPrices. The Order's ShippingOption also has a ShippingPrice, and so on. Pricing is then handled by another parallel structure of price calculators - you give an Order to an OrderPriceCalculator, and it gives you back an OrderPrice. In doing so, it will send each Item to the ItemPriceCalculator, which will send each Option to the OptionPriceCalculator, and so on.

The price objects can refer to the order objects, but not vice versa. Our system does actually persist the prices, but separately from the orders.

The advantage of this is that it separates the concerns of describing the contents of an order, describing the price of an order, and calculating the price of an order.

The disadvantage is that you have a huge number of classes, and the information you need is, inevitably, never in the objects you have to hand.

The disadvantage probably outweighs the advantage.